# For frame[base_link]: No transform to fixed frame using IMU

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, fixed-frame, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a mobile robot and I would like it to navigate around a room and I already have a map of the room. I am using rotary encoders for odometry. I am using [robot_pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf) to merge data from rotary encoders and IMU. I am using [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) for localization and [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) for planning. Now the problem is, when I set the fixed frame in RVIZ as map, the status of IMU keeps on oscillating from `Status:OK` to following:

[image: image description]

The tf tree is shown which looks good to me:
[C:\fakepath\tf_tree.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14313589068939156.png)

**IMU part of the Code**
For IMU, I am using http://wiki.ros.org/phidgets_imu and http://wiki.ros.org/imu_filter_madgwick.

```
<!-- IMU -->
<node pkg="phidgets_imu" type="phidgets_imu_node" name="IMU_node1" output="screen">
    <param name="frame_id" value="base_link"/>
</node>
<node pkg="imu_filter_madgwick" type="imu_filter_node" name="IMU_node2" output="screen">
    <param name="use_mag" value="false"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="false"/>
    <param name="fixed_frame" value="odom_combined"/>
    <remap from="/imu/data" to="/imu_data"/>    
</node>
```

I am not able to figure out why is this happening because frame id of IMU is base_link and transformation exists between it and the map as can be seen in the tf tree. Does anyone have any idea as to what might be causing this?

Thanks a lot.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208998/for-frame%5Bbase_link%5D:-no-transform-to-fixed-frame-using-imu/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the reason why it flickers is that at the time the IMU message arrives, the TF that you're missing is not there yet most of the time. There's a race condition: when the TF with time stamp "t1" arrives before the IMU message with time stamp "t2", where t1 >= t2, it flickers to black, and otherwise to red.

The solution would be to fix the IMU RViz plugin: there should probably be a `tf::waitForTransform()` in there. But the problem is purely cosmetic; everything else should be working, right?

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-05-13**:
That makes sense. I changed the parameter `period`  in the [phidgets_imu](http://wiki.ros.org/phidgets_imu) from 8 ms to 32 ms and the issue got resolved. Yaa.. everything else seems to be working...Thanks!